# file_get_contents is not able to read image from facebook image url

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, file-get-contents

I have got an image url from facebook:

```
https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/s720x720/156510_443901075651849_1975839315_n.jpg
```

I need to save this in my local. when i used `file_get_contents` it gave error `failed to open stream`. when i open image in the browser it is showing fine. I just understand how to do it.

infact i used curl in the following way and got no response at all

$url = https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/s720x720/156510_443901085651849_1975839315_n.jpg;

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$filename = 'ex'.$src['photo_id'].'.jpg';
$imgRes = imagecreatefromstring($response);
imagejpeg($imgRes, $filename, 70);

header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
imagejpeg($imgRes, NULL, 70);
```

Comment: Your setup probably doesn't allow url_fopen. You'd might need to use curl instead.

Comment: +1 ^ CURL is a better option anyway.

Comment: may i know how to use curl to extract the image

Comment: used curl but couldn't get any response

Comment: It's to do with SSL. Try it with http:// instead. Or use a signed certificate when using CURL.

Comment: Is that you on the picture :-) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are requesting an secure URL and your server probably doesn't support it without configuration. You can either use CURL to request the URL with a valid certificate or just try and request it without SSL:

```
<?php

$file = 'http://url/to_image.jpg';
$data = file_get_contents($file);

header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo $data;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell cURL that you don't wan't to verify the SSL connection.

The following is tested and works.

```
$url = "https://******";


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // ignore SSL verifying
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that Facebook requires a valid User-Agent string and is denying your request because `file_get_contents` doesn't send one when accessing remote files.

You could use this:

```
if( $f = fsockopen($host="fbcdn-sphotos-e-a-.akamaihd.net",80)) {
    fputs($f,"GET /hphotos-ak-prn1/........ HTTP/1.0\r\n"
            ."Host: ".$host."\r\n"
            ."User-Agent: My Image Downloader\r\n\r\n");
    $ret = "";
    $headers = true;
    while(!feof($f)) {
        $line = fgets($f);
        if( $headers) {
            if( trim($line) == "") $headers = false;
        }
        else $ret .= $line;
    }
    fclose($f);
    file_put_contents("mylocalfile.png",$ret);
}
```

Comment: Could just put header("User-Agent: My Image Downloader"); and keep everything else the same no?

Comment: No, that would send the header to the browser requesting the PHP page.

Comment: You could also use `ini_set('user_agent', 'My Image Downloader');` to set an user agent.

Comment: Ah, that's true. I forgot about that setting.